# Create the frequency count from a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

Suppose there is a vector with numerical values with possible duplicated values

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3)
```

I want to create another vector of counts as follows.

1. It has the same length as `x`.
2. For each unique value in `x`, the first appearance is 1, the second appearance is 2, and so on.

The new vector I want is

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2
```

I need a fast way of doing this since `x` can be really long.

Comment: I don't believe the "This question already has answers here:" link is the same.  That's about row numbers; this is about counts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ave` and `seq_along`:

```
> x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3)
> ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 2
```

---

Another option to consider is `data.table`. Although it is a little bit more work, it might pay off on very long vectors.

Here it is on your example--definitely seems like overkill!

```
library(data.table)

x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3)
DT <- data.table(id = sequence(length(x)), x, key = "id")
DT[, y := sequence(.N), by = x][, y]
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 2
```

But how about on a vector 10,000,000 items long?

```
set.seed(1)
x2 <- sample(100, 1e7, replace = TRUE)

funAve <- function() {
  ave(x2, x2, FUN = seq_along)
}

funDT <- function() {
  DT <- data.table(id = sequence(length(x2)), x2, key = "id")
  DT[, y := sequence(.N), by = x2][, y]
}

identical(funAve(), funDT())
# [1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
# Unit: seconds
#      expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  funAve() 6.727557 6.792743 6.827117 6.992609 7.352666    20
#   funDT() 1.967795 2.029697 2.053886 2.070462 2.123531    20
```